# How to find the area bounded by two curves?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

find the area bounded by the curves 
$y = x^2$ and $y = 5x-6$.

First method I tried was to find where the two curves meet, which is at $x = 2, x =3$.

Then integrated $x^2$ with limits from $0$ to $2$ and subtracted the integral of $5x-6$ withs limits from $0$ to $2$
got $4.67$ as the answer but was marked wrong.

Comment: Try integrating between $x=2$ and $x=3$.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words here!

Comment: The good news: your computation of the integral from $0$ to $2$ is right ! The bad news: this is not what was asked ! Why didn't you integrate from $2$ to $3$ ?

Answer (score 3):

It's just $\int\limits_2^3(5x-6-x^2)dx=\left.\frac{5x^2}{2}-6x-\frac{x^3}{3}\right|_2^3=\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: Try formatting the middle part with `\left` & `\right` like this: `\left . \frac{5x^2}{2}-6x-\frac{x^3}{3}\right|_2^3`

Comment: @CiaPan Wow!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: More at Meta: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/152299). There's also [Do we have an equation editing HOWTO?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/152299) with even more info, however not about \left and \right. :)

Answer (score 0):

You know the intersection of the curves is at $x = 2, x = 3$, so simply find which curve is "above" the other in the y-axis within these bounds (it's $y = 5x - 6$) and subtract the other function ($y = x^2$). So your final integral is $\int_2^3 5x - 6 - x^2 dx = \frac{5}{2}x^2 - 6x - \frac{1}{3}x^3|_2^3 = 1/6$. You just made a mistake in choosing your bounds.